# mobile web page, but it didn't take occupy the full screen

Tags: html, css, mobile

Trying to write a mobile web page, but it doesn't take the full screen on the emulated mobile page (neither on my LG Pro mobile phone).  Any reason why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Application</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
        *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
        input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
        body { background-color:white; color:black }
    </style>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" />
    <script src="http://dbushell.github.io/Responsive-Off-Canvas-Menu/js/modernizr.js"></script>

    <!--[if (gt IE 8) | (IEMobile)]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dbushell.github.io/Responsive-Off-Canvas-Menu/css/step4.css">

</head>
<body style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; height=100%">
    <!-- content goes here-->
<div id="outer-wrap" style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; height=100%">
<div id="inner-wrap" style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; height=100%">

    <header id="top" role="banner">
        <div class="block">
            <h1 class="block-title">List</h1>
            <a class="nav-btn" id="nav-open-btn" href="#nav">Book Navigation</a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
        <div class="block">
            <h2 class="block-title">Chapters</h2>
            <ul>
                <li class="is-active"><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Two</a>
                </li><!--
             --><li>
                    <a href="#">Three</a>
                </li><!--
             --><li>
                    <a href="#">Four</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="#">Five</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Eight</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nine</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="close-btn" id="nav-close-btn" href="#top">Return to Content</a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="main" role="main" style="height=100%">
        <article class="block prose">

            <h1>Welcome To John's recollection</h1>

            Wonderful things in life


        </article>

    </div>

    <footer role="contentinfo">
        <div class="block prose">
            <p class="small">Copyright © John &amp; Joe</p>

        </div>
    </footer>

</div>
<!--/#inner-wrap-->
</div>
<!--/#outer-wrap-->

<script src="http://dbushell.github.io/Responsive-Off-Canvas-Menu/js/main.js"></script>
<script>
    // When ready...
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you got some typos that you need to fix:
Take a look at body style attribute (height value), you wrote:

```
<body style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; **height=100%"**>
```

But you need:

```
<body style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; **height:100%"**>
```

First fix those kind of typos on page.

ONE BIG MISTAKE is to make your "body" absolute. Please take a look at how positioning really works.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

To fix this, remove from "body" positioning at all. And make another element(div in your case), that will be positioned absolute, if you really need that.

For more help, try to make some live example of your project so we can inspect it better.

Without seeing what you done in CSS we can't be sure that this answer will fix your problem.

But it looks like you misunderstand concept of positioning, and over complicated your DOM and CSS.

Comment: Thanks @Zlatko Vujicic.  Replaced "=" after height.   However, I remove "style" attribute in body,  web page is empty.  Not sure why.    The HTML page has a URL pointing to css ("http://dbushell.github.io/Responsive-Off-Canvas-Menu/css/step4.css").   Note that I am not a UI developer, I am just trying to get this done as simple/fast as possible :-)

Comment: well this code needs revision,  I can't access that css file (error 404) so it might be that you're not even loading it. Check that out,  than you can go to JSFiddle and prepare some quick overview so we can inspect it. A lot of absolute elements in DOM confuse me,  and it's possibly that those elements are not built well.  Also try to add width to your elements.

Comment: I can get it by "wget http://dbushell.github.io/Responsive-Off-Canvas-Menu/css/step4.css".    If you still have trouble accessing this css file,  can you try:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qy1vxpnyv3pezs8/step4.css?dl=0?   Thanks.

Comment: I'm not at home st the moment,  but I'll check it for sure

Comment: Ok, page seems to render perfect on all devices that have min-width: 320px. So can you tell me resolution of your phone, and confirm it on this website http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/ (open it from your LG Pro please).

Comment: My LG Pro is 360 x 640.  When you say it renders perfectly on yours,  does the white part of the web page occupy the screen all the way to the bottom?  In my case, it only occupy a little more than the half way from top to bottom.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you. Do you need white part to occupy whole page, so that you got sticky footer on the bottom? Or you need some minimum height for white part. What result you need?

Comment: Ok, if you got case that you want sticky footer, this would be a way to do it. I already took "sticky footer"  for one of my projects.

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

use this meta tags :

```
<meta content="width=device-width,height=device-height,inital-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

and for responsive design YOU should use  Media queries in your css

Comment: Thanks @mehdi,    Now the article section will take 100% of screen and don't see "footer" any more.  If I remove the attribute "style" for the div with id "main", then the article will shrink and the web page page only takes half of the screen.   Media queries is interesting.  I will need to check it out.  Do you happen to have any quick tip on using Media queries to expand the article section so that the web page will take entire screen (with footer visible)?

Comment: actually media query can help you easily ... take a look to my new answer

Answer (score 0):

Media query is an easy way like this css code :

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
#bgimg1{display:none}
#bgimg{display:block}
.usertext{font-size:30px;}
.no_order2{font-size:20px;margin:auto 20%;margin-top:35%;}
#show-time{left:-15%;}
}
```

you can use `!important` to run your new codes over previous code

Comment: I guess in theory it's possible to do some math:  get the screen height, subtract the heights of header and foot, use the resulted value as the height of the article.  Just wonder if there is a simple way to do it.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of mehdi and Zlatko Vujicic, created a hack which appears to serve the purpose. The change?  Moved footer to the immediate parent div of ,  use the idea of sticky css (thanks Zlatko Vujicic) to extend the height of the above mentioned div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Application</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta content="width=device-width,height=device-height,inital-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
        *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
        input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
        body { background-color:white; color:black }
        .wrapper1 {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
/*height: 100%;*/
margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
    </style>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" />
    <script src="http://dbushell.github.io/Responsive-Off-Canvas-Menu/js/modernizr.js"></script>

    <!--[if (gt IE 8) | (IEMobile)]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dbushell.github.io/Responsive-Off-Canvas-Menu/css/step4.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        @media screen and (max-width:600px{
#bgimg1{display:none}
#bgimg{display:block}
.usertext{font-size:30px;}
.no_order2{font-size:20px;margin:auto 20%;margin-top:35%;}
#show-time{left:-15%;}
}
    </style>

</head>
<body style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%">
    <!-- content goes here-->
<div id="outer-wrap" style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%">
<div id="inner-wrap" style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%">

    <header id="top" role="banner">
        <div class="block">
            <h1 class="block-title">List</h1>
            <a class="nav-btn" id="nav-open-btn" href="#nav">Book Navigation</a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
        <div class="block">
            <h2 class="block-title">Chapters</h2>
            <ul>
                <li class="is-active"><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Two</a>
                </li><!--
             --><li>
                    <a href="#">Three</a>
                </li><!--
             --><li>
                    <a href="#">Four</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="#">Five</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Eight</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nine</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="close-btn" id="nav-close-btn" href="#top">Return to Content</a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="main" role="main" class="wrapper1">
        <article class="block prose">

            <h1>Welcome To John's recollection</h1>

            Wonderful things in life
    <footer role="contentinfo" style="height: 4em; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%">
            <p align="center" class="small" style="position: relative; top: 40%">Copyright © John &amp; Joe</p>
    </footer>

        </article>

    </div>


</div>
<!--/#inner-wrap-->
</div>
<!--/#outer-wrap-->

<script src="http://dbushell.github.io/Responsive-Off-Canvas-Menu/js/main.js"></script>
<script>
    // When ready...
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```